# .Net Project not updating when publishing to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

When I publish to Azure, my dev-ops pipeline completes successfully, however the actual application does not update as per the changes I have made.

I have tried publishing this manually and still experience the same issue. I have tried everything I can think of and everything I have seen online, however I cannot work out what is causing this.

I have disabled caching on the web-app, I have disabled browser cache and have tried from multiple machines. I have tried restarting the web-app, stopping, running the pipeline, then starting it amongst a number of different things.

This is a .Net 7 application running C# 11.

Has anyone else experienced this? I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Have you merged the code to the deploying branch?

Comment: @AjayManagaon I have, I have also tried branching off to a new branch and publishing that, and still the same issue.

Comment: Can you share your deployment file? yml?

Comment: @AjayManagaon I have fixed this now, thank you for helping anyway. Answer will be below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the issue to this.

After removal of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design` package this now functions as expected.

I hope this helps others.